# How can I pass an id target to angular ui-sref for scroll/load at different element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm pretty new to angular. trying to build this app.

I have the following states:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: '/static/guest/templates/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            resolve: {
                authenticate: redirectAfter('profile', null)
            }
        })

        .state('profileSettings', {
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: '/static/guest/templates/profile-settings.html',
            controller: 'ProfileSettingsCtrl',
            resolve: {
                authenticate: redirectAfter('profileSettings', null)
            }
        })
```

I have the following link on my profile page that links to settings.

```
<a class="pull-right" ui-sref="profileSettings"><strong>Edit</strong></a>
```

I want to know how I can pass an id target identifier on `ui-sref="profileSettings"` so that instead of `/settings` that link goes to `/settings#element`

The goal is that upon clicking that link I am taken to the element passed to the settings url via the id target. Is this possible? I have only been able to find information regarding passing parameters but nothing regarding id targets.

Comment: Could you pass the element id to `#stateParams`? Then on the `$viewContentLoaded` event, go to that element.

Comment: @JoshBeam coud you provide an example? Like I mentioned I am new to angular and didn't even know about $viewContentLoaded. Is that a javascript event in the DOM? Would i reference that in my controller or where?

Comment: I am using 'ui.router'